# JQuery - plus/minus set max number Classic ASP script

Tags: jquery, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a few blocks of JQuery code which ties in to some html buttons I have which increment a number by either 1 or 10.  Problem is, it's against a figure which varies as a maximum (as in a stock level).

I've tried adding some code into this block but the entire code fails to run.  I'm fairly new with JQuery but how would I add a "max" attribute to this? (I'd cheat and because it's being used in Classic ASP I'd place <% %> tags within for the variable maximum figure).

```
$('.qtyplus10').click(function(e){
        // Stop acting like a button
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the field name
        fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
        // Get its current value
        var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
        // If is not undefined
        if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
            // Increment
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 10);
        } else {
            // Otherwise put a 0 there
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(1);
        }
    });
```

If the use of <% %> asp code within JQuery isn't really acceptable (even though it works) what would be an alternative method?

Comment: Why is using <% %> within jQuery considered unacceptable, can you explain? I do this often, but with PHP.

Comment: Looking over your code it is difficult to tell what the max value you are comparing against is. can you clarify: 1. If the max value is a field value not in this code or if it is an asp variable 2. If you only want to check before the increment or possibly do a partial increment up to the max.

Comment: @mikehomme using <% %> is not considered unacceptable under normal circumstances. Some programmers will avoid it though because it will prevent you from seperating this code. Basically if you are doing this optimally it should be in a seperate js file to allow for caching which would mean you would not have access to the asp framework. if it is on an asp page though than the OP was misinformed and using those tags are fine.

Comment: It is used on an ASP page - I just wasn't sure shoe-horning in other code types (Classic ASP into JQuery) would be acceptable, but if it is, that's fine, will do what I need it to.

Comment: And as I saw the code, I placed an `if` after the `else` prior to the `// Otherwise put a 0 there` which basically said `if (<% response.write(Max) %> > currentVal) { $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(<% response.write(Max) %>);` or code to that effect, as I said I don't know JQuery well enough but logically that's how I see the code.

Comment: That should be fine. I would only make 2 comments 1. (personal preference) use <%= %> instead of adding response.write every time. 2. Be aware of the limitation of your code. Max is only valid when the page is loaded in the browser not when the button is pressed. I imagine you know 2 but I work with people who sometimes forget that so I just always mention it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I knew that it would be a static figure when the page loaded - essentially, I'm getting the maximum value of a table and don't want to allow the + - options to go above that (currently I have a where greater than to stop more being taken out than is actually in the stock level)